# Rails nested delegate attributes not being updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :meta, class_name: SeoMetum, as: :metumable, dependent: :destroy
  delegate :browser_title, :browser_title=, :meta_description, :meta_description=, to: :meta

  has_one :collection
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collection

  after_save :save_meta_tags!

  def save_meta_tags!
    meta.save
  end
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :meta, class_name: SeoMetum, as: :metumable, dependent: :destroy
  delegate :browser_title, :browser_title=, :meta_description, :meta_description=, to: :meta

    belongs_to :user

  after_save :save_meta_tags!

  def save_meta_tags!
    meta.save
  end
end

class SeoMetum < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :metumable, :browser_title, :meta_description, :meta_keywords, :meta_author
  belongs_to :metumable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Here's what works:**

```
  it 'meta_description' do
    user.meta_description = 'This is my description of the user for search results.'
    user.meta_description.should == 'This is my description of the user for search results.'
  end

  it 'meta_description' do
    the_collection = user.collection
    the_collection.meta_description = 'This is my description of the user for search results.'
    the_collection.meta_description.should == 'This is my description of the user for search results.'
  end
```

**Here's what doesn't work**

```
  it 'meta_description' do
    user.collection.meta_description = 'This is my description of the user for search results.'
    user.collection.meta_description.should == 'This is my description of the user for search results.'
  end
  # => nil
```

My question is why doesn't the delegated attributes get updated within a nested attribute.  Where should I start looking to figure this out?  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you delegating the setter methods? You should just be delegating the attributes

Comment: My tests fail without having them.  I made a standalone rails app for it on https://github.com/ScotterC/delegate-association-rails-bug and reposted a more detailed version of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094910/rails-association-with-delegate-methods-possible-bug-with-ar